# how to enable textbox ,when uncheck a checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-4

I have 5 teachers names and corresponding checkboxes(5) I am using `checkall` function to check all check boxes.

now I want ,when I uncheck a checkbox now enable a textbox at right side.
how to create a textbox from unchecked function using javascript?
my code is :

**HTML + PHP :**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check form-control" id="checkFull">
<div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('check')) ? 'has error' : '' }}">
    <label for="check" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{$teacher->tname}}:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="hidden" id="{{$teacher->user_id}}" name="{{$teacher->user_id}}" value="0">
        <input id="{{$teacher->user_id}}" name="{{$teacher->user_id}}" type="checkbox" value="1" class="check form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="textBox">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
$("#checkFull").click(function() {
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

what is the javascript code to enable textbox?

Comment: Please show us the HTML *after* it has been parsed.

Comment: i want only ...how to enable or display a  textbox when already checked checkbox is go to  uncheck .using  javascript

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeTextBoxFormCheckBox($elm){
  var $textBox= $elm.closest(".form-group").find("input[type='text']");
  if($elm.is(":checked")){
   $textBox.attr("disabled",true);
  }else{
   $textBox.attr("disabled",false);
  }
 }
 $(".checkbox").each(function(){
  changeTextBoxFormCheckBox($(this));
 })
 $("#checkFull").click(function () {
  var checkAllProp= $(this).prop('checked');
  $(".checkbox").each(function(){
   var $this=$(this);
   $this.prop('checked', checkAllProp);
   changeTextBoxFormCheckBox($(this));
  })
 });
 $(".checkbox").click(function () {
  changeTextBoxFormCheckBox($(this));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check form-control" id="checkFull"> 
   <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('check')) ? 'has error' : '' }}">
              <label for="check" class="col-sm-4 control-label">tname:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">

                <input type="hidden" id="{{$teacher->user_id}}" name="{{$teacher->user_id}}" value="0">

                <input id="{{$teacher->user_id}}" name="{{$teacher->user_id}}" type="checkbox" value="1" class="check form-control checkbox">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="textBox">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your html code as I mentioned. You can do change as per your need

```js
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#textBox1").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    } else {
        $("#textBox1").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">  
    <div class="col-sm-4 teacherContent">  
        <input type="hidden" id="teacherId1" name="teacherName1" value="0"> 
        <input type="hidden" id="teacherId2" name="teacherName2" value="1">           
        <input id="teacherCheck_1" class="teacherCheck" name="teacherCheckName1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="check form-control">
        <input id="teacherCheck_2" class="teacherCheck" name="teacherCheckName2" type="checkbox" value="1" class="check form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="textBox1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not work ..problem is the first checkbox only work .not other checkboxes are not work... i thought  the textboxes are more than one.. but passing value is id=textBox1....so id  take only one value in function.

Comment: I am not getting your exact question. Do you have separate textbox for each checkbox or what?

Comment: 1st iam use checkall to checked all checkboxes.then im go to uncheck  any checkbox ,want enable  textbox near to that unchecked checkbox. if iam using this code  click cheall and checked all checkboxes and also disable all textboxes...then iam go to uncheck any checkbox enable all textboxes..i want only enabled  unchecked checkbox  corresponding textbox not all

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
     var val = $(this).data('value');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   
     $("#textBox"+val).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    } else {
        $("#textBox"+val).removeAttr("disabled"); 
    } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">  
    <div class="col-sm-4 teacherContent">  
        <input type="hidden" id="teacherId1" name="teacherName1" value="0"> 
        <input type="hidden" id="teacherId2" name="teacherName2" value="1">           
        <input id="teacherCheck_1" data-value="1" name="teacherCheckName1" type="checkbox" class="check form-control">
        <input type="text" id="textBox1">
        <input id="teacherCheck_2" data-value="2" class="teacherCheck" name="teacherCheckName2" type="checkbox" class="check form-control">
        <input type="text" id="textBox2">
    </div>
   
</div>
```